# Convert a Julian date into Gregorian day in R

Tags: r, date, dataframe, gregorian-calendar, julian-date

I have a dataframe with dates like 116032 on julian format . 1YYDDD, where YY are the 2 last digits of the year and DDD the day on that year, the firts 1 is always fix.

So `116032`      is `01-02-2016`.

I want to convert this julian dates into normal gregorian dates on R. I have researched looking for a library or something but with no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the base R function `as.Date` together with the proper format.

```
as.Date("116032", "1%y%j")
[1] "2016-02-01"
```

The first argument to as.Date is your values (as a character vector). If needed, you can convert this vector to character using `as.character`. The second, "1%y%j", is the format of the each element of the vector. The 1 is a throw away term to account for your first character, the "%y" reads in the next two digits as the year, and the "%j" will read in the the following three digits as the number of days from the start of the year.

To learn more about the available formats for dates (and times), see `?strptime`.